# Finding the splitting field of $f(x) = x^4 + 10x^2+5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I found that the roots of $f(x) = x^4+10x^2+5$ are $\pm i\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}$ and $\pm i\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}$, then the splitting field of this polynomial over the rationals is
$K := \mathbb{Q}{(i\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}},i\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}})}$.

However, I have to prove that the degree of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is 4, and that happens only if $K=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}})$, so in this case I need to find out that $i\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}\in \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}})$, but I cannot show this by field operations.

Can anyone give me a hint to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You question has $x^2$ where your title has just $x.$

Comment: Hint: consider the product $$i\sqrt{5+2\sqrt5}\cdot i\sqrt{5-2\sqrt5}.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes! There was a typo in the title. I already corrected it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, $K$ is the splitting field of the polynomial.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've done it! Thanks for your hint!